# Symfony Installation - Could not find package

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm launching the following command in DOS :

```
php c:\composer.phar create-project C:\Symfony C:\Users\Jerome\git\XX\XX
```

I got this error:

> Invalid argument exception, could not find package C:\Symfony but all
>   the files are there.

Here is the screen shot!
[image: Symfony 1]

[image: Symfony 2]

Comment: We can see nothing in your screenshot

Comment: oh ok i will fix that sorry ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command you need is:

```
php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition C:\Users\Jerome\git\XX\XX 2.1.2
```

`symfony/framework-standard-edition` is not a path, it is a package name